# Problemas com atualização de atributo

Tags: jsf

Boa tarde.

Estou com um problema para instanciar um novo objeto de um tipo X toda vez que clicar no botão "Novo". Vou anexar o bean, a view e dois prints (atualizar e novo).

Editar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Novo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ManagedBean

```
@ManagedBean(name="controleBean")
@SessionScoped
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class ControleBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Bomba_Reservatorio bombaReservatorio;
    private Bomba bomba;
    private Historico historico;
    private Placa placa;
    private Porta porta;
    private Reservatorio reservatorio;
    private TipoPorta tipoPorta;

    private Bomba_Reservatorio bombaReservatorioSelecao;
    private Bomba bombaSelecao;
    private Historico historicoSelecao;
    private Placa placaSelecao;
    private Porta portaSelecao;
    private Reservatorio reservatorioSelecao;
    private TipoPorta tipoPortaSelecao;

    private List<Bomba_Reservatorio> bombasReservatorios;
    private List<Bomba> bombas;
    private List<Historico> historicos;
    private List<Placa> placas;
    private List<Porta> portas;
    private List<Reservatorio> reservatorios;
    private List<TipoPorta> tiposPortas;

    private Bomba_ReservatorioDAO bombaReservatorioDAO = new Bomba_ReservatorioDAO();
    private BombaDAO bombaDAO = new BombaDAO();
    private HistoricoDAO historicoDAO = new HistoricoDAO();
    private PlacaDAO placaDAO = new PlacaDAO();
    private PortaDAO portaDAO = new PortaDAO();
    private ReservatorioDAO reservatorioDAO = new ReservatorioDAO();
    private TipoPortaDAO tipoPortaDAO = new TipoPortaDAO();

    /***************************************/
    /*********** Métodos Próprios **********/
    /***************************************/

    /***************************************/
    /************** Métodos DAO ************/
    /***************************************/

    public void novaBombaReservatorio() {
        bombaReservatorio = new Bomba_Reservatorio();
    }

    public void novaBomba() {
        bomba = new Bomba();
    }

    public void novoHistorico() {
        historico = new Historico();
    }

    public void novaPlaca() {
        placa = new Placa();
    }

    public void novaPorta() {
        porta = new Porta();
    }

    public void novoReservatorio() {
        reservatorio = new Reservatorio();
    }

    public void novoTipoPorta() {
        tipoPorta = new TipoPorta();
    }

    public void cadastrarBombaReservatorio() {
        bombaReservatorioDAO.salvar(bombaReservatorio);
    }

    public void cadastrarBomba() {
        bombaDAO.salvar(bomba);
    }

    public void cadastrarHistorico() {
        historicoDAO.salvar(historico);
    }

    public void cadastrarPlaca() {
        placaDAO.salvar(placa);
    }

    public void cadastrarPorta() {
        portaDAO.salvar(porta);
    }

    public void cadastrarReservatorio() {
        reservatorioDAO.salvar(reservatorio);
    }

    public void cadastrarTipoPorta() {
        tipoPortaDAO.salvar(tipoPorta);
    }

    public void excluirBombaReservatorio() {
        bombaReservatorioDAO.excluir(bombaReservatorioSelecao);
    }

    public void excluirBomba() {
        bombaDAO.excluir(bombaSelecao);
    }

    public void excluirHistorico() {
        historicoDAO.excluir(historicoSelecao);
    }

    public void excluirPlaca() {
        placaDAO.excluir(placaSelecao);
    }

    public void excluirPorta() {
        portaDAO.excluir(portaSelecao);
    }

    public void excluirReservatorio() {
        reservatorioDAO.excluir(reservatorioSelecao);
    }

    public void excluirTipoPorta() {
        tipoPortaDAO.excluir(tipoPortaSelecao);
    }

    /***************************************/
    /********** Getters e Setters **********/
    /***************************************/

    public Bomba_Reservatorio getBombaReservatorio() {
        return bombaReservatorio == null ? bombaReservatorio = new Bomba_Reservatorio() : bombaReservatorio;
    }

    public void setBombaReservatorio(Bomba_Reservatorio bombaReservatorio) {
        this.bombaReservatorio = bombaReservatorio;
    }

    public Bomba getBomba() {
        return bomba == null ? bomba = new Bomba() : bomba;
    }

    public void setBomba(Bomba bomba) {
        this.bomba = bomba;
    }

    public Historico getHistorico() {
        return historico == null ? historico = new Historico() : historico;
    }

    public void setHistorico(Historico historico) {
        this.historico = historico;
    }

    public Placa getPlaca() {
        return placa == null ? placa = new Placa() : placa;
    }

    public void setPlaca(Placa placa) {
        this.placa = placa;
    }

    public Porta getPorta() {
        return porta == null ? porta = new Porta() : porta;
    }

    public void setPorta(Porta porta) {
        this.porta = porta;
    }

    public Reservatorio getReservatorio() {
        return reservatorio == null ? reservatorio = new Reservatorio() : reservatorio;
    }

    public void setReservatorio(Reservatorio reservatorio) {
        this.reservatorio = reservatorio;
    }

    public TipoPorta getTipoPorta() {
        return tipoPorta == null ? tipoPorta = new TipoPorta() : tipoPorta;
    }

    public void setTipoPorta(TipoPorta tipoPorta) {
        this.tipoPorta = tipoPorta;
    }

    public Bomba_Reservatorio getBombaReservatorioSelecao() {
        return bombaReservatorioSelecao;
    }

    public void setBombaReservatorioSelecao(Bomba_Reservatorio bombaReservatorioSelecao) {
        this.bombaReservatorioSelecao = bombaReservatorioSelecao;
    }

    public Bomba getBombaSelecao() {
        return bombaSelecao;
    }

    public void setBombaSelecao(Bomba bombaSelecao) {
        this.bombaSelecao = bombaSelecao;
    }

    public Historico getHistoricoSelecao() {
        return historicoSelecao;
    }

    public void setHistoricoSelecao(Historico historicoSelecao) {
        this.historicoSelecao = historicoSelecao;
    }

    public Placa getPlacaSelecao() {
        return placaSelecao;
    }

    public void setPlacaSelecao(Placa placaSelecao) {
        this.placaSelecao = placaSelecao;
    }

    public Porta getPortaSelecao() {
        return portaSelecao;
    }

    public void setPortaSelecao(Porta portaSelecao) {
        this.portaSelecao = portaSelecao;
    }

    public Reservatorio getReservatorioSelecao() {
        return reservatorioSelecao;
    }

    public void setReservatorioSelecao(Reservatorio reservatorioSelecao) {
        this.reservatorioSelecao = reservatorioSelecao;
    }

    public TipoPorta getTipoPortaSelecao() {
        return tipoPortaSelecao;
    }

    public void setTipoPortaSelecao(TipoPorta tipoPortaSelecao) {
        this.tipoPortaSelecao = tipoPortaSelecao;
    }

    public List<Bomba_Reservatorio> getBombasReservatorios() {
        return bombasReservatorios = bombaReservatorioDAO.listar();
    }

    public List<Bomba> getBombas() {
        return bombas = bombaDAO.listar();
    }

    public List<Historico> getHistoricos() {
        return historicos = historicoDAO.listar();
    }

    public List<Placa> getPlacas() {
        return placas = placaDAO.listar();
    }

    public List<Porta> getPortas() {
        return portas = portaDAO.listar();
    }

    public List<Reservatorio> getReservatorios() {
        return reservatorios = reservatorioDAO.listar();
    }

    public List<TipoPorta> getTiposPortas() {
        return tiposPortas = tipoPortaDAO.listar();
    }

}
```

placa.xhtml

```
<p:commandButton value="Novo" icon="ui-icon-document"
    actionListener="#{controleBean.novaPlaca()}" process="@this"
    update="dataTable" oncomplete="PF('tipoPortaDialog').show()"
    class="botaoDataTable">
    <p:resetInput target="tipoPorta-dialog" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Desde já, muito obrigado!

Comment: Você quer clicar no botão novo e abrir o modal com os campos em branco?

Comment: Isso!! Mas também reinstanciar o objeto. Clicou -> novoObjeto() -> abre Dialog

Comment: coloca um sysout dentro do seu método pra ver se eles está sendo chamado.

Comment: Ok. Farei um teste amanhã, quando estarei mexendo no projeto. Em seguida, posto o que rolar aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz alguns testes e constatei que o método de instanciar estava sendo chamado. Contudo, faltava eu colocar o dialog dentro do update para ele zerar os formulários.

```
<p:commandButton value="Novo" icon="ui-icon-document"
    actionListener="#{controleBean.novaPlaca()}" process="@this"
    update="dataTable placa-dialog" oncomplete="PF('placaDialog').show()"
    class="botaoDataTable">
        <p:resetInput target="placa-dialog" />
</p:commandButton>
```